# Reference implementation of Scheme macro system

Tags: compiler-construction, macros, scheme, r5rs

Does there exist a reference implementation of the Scheme macro system? That is, an open source implementation of RxRS macros, that's written in portable Scheme rather than in terms of compiler internals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reference implementation, but a portable implementation used by many Scheme systems is [psyntax](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/chezscheme/r6rs-libraries/).